# aria2c - Any way to keep only list of failed downloads?

Tags: terminal, download, aria2

I am using `aria2c` to download a quite large list of urls (~6000) organized in a text file.

Based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jonbakerfish/0f7877c050b648169e0958ea2e2c6aca), I am using the following script to download all the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
aria2c -j5 -i list.txt -c --save-session out.txt
has_error=`wc -l < out.txt`

while [ $has_error -gt 0 ]
do
  echo "still has $has_error errors, rerun aria2 to download ..."
  aria2c -j5 -i list.txt -c --save-session out.txt
  has_error=`wc -l < out.txt`
  sleep 10
done

### PS: one line solution, just loop 1000 times
###         seq 1000 | parallel -j1 aria2c -i list.txt -c
```

which saves all the `aria2c` output in a text file, and in case of at least one download error, tries to download all urls again.

The problem is: since my url list is so large, this becomes pretty inefficient. If 30 files result in download error (say, because of a server timeout), then the whole list will be looped over again 30 times.

So, the question is: is there any way to tell `aria2c` to save only the failed downloads, and then try to re-download only those files?

Comment: Did you try [--input-file](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-i)=out.txt upon restart? The description of [--save-session](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-save-session) states: _“You can pass this output file to aria2c with --input-file option on restart.”_ That is in your while-loop, you use the previous `out.txt` as input to aria2c, rename it to `in.txt` for example before re-starting aria2c.